# Cut and paste from Twilio blog is returning invalid TwiML

Tags: twilio, twilio-twiml

I'm trying to do something pretty simple that is straight from the Twilio blog at https://www.twilio.com/blog/2009/05/dialing-multiple-numbers-simultaneously-with-twilio.html

Namely, this:

```
<?xml version=“1.0” encoding=“UTF-8”?>
<Response>
    <Dial action=“/handleDialStatus.php” method=“GET”>
        <Number>877-555-1212</Number>
        <Number>877-999-1234</Number>
        <Number>877-123-4567</Number>
    </Dial>
</Response>
```

But it's returning 'Invalid TwiML'.

Any ideas?

Comment: Whoops - not sure why, but my cut and paste code didn't paste (the bit with the numbers). Will try to paste as comment

Comment: <?xml version=“1.0” encoding=“UTF-8”?>

<Response>

<Dial>

    <Number>877-555-1212</Number>

    <Number>877-999-1234</Number>

    <Number>877-123-4567</Number>

</Dial>

</Response>

Comment: Looks like the snippet above has "smart quotes" in it instead of regular quotes.  Try replacing the quotes once you've pasted the snippet into your text editor.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

As Devin suggested in the comments, it looks like the blog post had smart quotes in the XML. The XML you need instead is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
  <Dial action="/handleDialStatus.php" method="GET">
    <Number>877-555-1212</Number>
    <Number>877-999-1234</Number>
    <Number>877-123-4567</Number>
  </Dial>
</Response>
```

I've updated [the original blog post](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2009/05/dialing-multiple-numbers-simultaneously-with-twilio.html) to fix this issue there too.

Let me know if this helps at all.

Comment: No problem! Just trying to help :)